# after login redirect to page where session was timeout in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

after my session time out i redirect to login page but when i login again i should redirect to the page where the session was timed out.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [Tour] and read [Ask]. Then come back and revisit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

When you are redirecting to login page then concatenate the path with present page URL like :

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
Response.Redirect = string.Format("www.example.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl={0}",path);
```

Then on Login page after login is successful then you can do something like this:

```
var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
Response.Redirect = string.Format("{0}/{1}",HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host,returnUrl );
```

Comment: thank you for the help but what it session was timed out automatically.

Comment: From you question above it seems that you are able to redirect to login page after session time out. Kindly edit the question accordingly to make us understand clearly.